# Objective C Alarm local notification

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have developed one application for alarm. I have used `local notification` with cancel and snooze alert buttons. Its working fine, but when application is offline how to set snooze?

I mean, how to open my app when the local notification is executed (so the user can snooze it)?

Comment: I think you need to reword your question - I cannot make head nor tail of it...

Comment: the users can open the application, if they want. you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with `UILocalNotification`. When it's executed, you can't open your app without the user authorization. Have you ever checked some alert app to iOS? You need to lets it open all night.

When the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method is called, you can set a local notification into 5 seconds, so you can alert your users to let your app opened.

Another way: You can set the local notification button to "snooze" and when the user presses it, your app's opened. Doing this, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method returns you if the user "snooze" it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif)
    {
        // The user snooze the alert. Insert another local notification here.
    }

    return YES;
}
```